# Squeeze Theorem: Finding the limit of a trig function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

I'm stuck on finding the limit of a complex fraction/trig function.  Could someone please assist, or point out where I'm going wrong?

> Determine
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(x+1)\cos(\ln(x^2))}{\sqrt{(x^2+2)}}$$

For all $x$: $$-1 \le \cos(\ln(x^2)) \le 1$$

Multiply by $(x+1)$:

$$-(x+1) \le (x+1)\cos(\ln(x^2)) \le (x+1)$$

Divide by $\sqrt{(x^2+2)}$:

$$\frac{-(x+1)}{\sqrt{(x^2+2)}} \le \frac{(x+1)\cos(\ln(x^2))}{\sqrt{(x^2+2)}} \le \frac{(x+1)}{\sqrt{(x^2+2)}}$$

Now to find the limits:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{-(x+1)}{\sqrt{(x^2+2)}} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{(2)}}$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(x+1)}{\sqrt{(x^2+2)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2)}}$$

This is where I get stuck.  My limits are not equal, so I cannot solve using the Squeeze Theorem.  I must've skipped a step or used the wrong approach, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Does the limit exist?

Comment: before trying to evaluate a limit you should first be sure that it exists. here the limit of $\frac{(x+1)}{\sqrt(x^2+2)}$ is just $\sqrt{2}^{-1}$, but $\cos(\ln x^2)$ will oscillate as $x \to 0$

Comment: I know the limit may not exist, but given the nature of my tutorial paper I had the impression that there is a limit to be found if the Squeeze Theorem is properly applied.  Do you see any flaws in my calculation?

Comment: The tutorial paper, then, gave the wrong impression.

Comment: Haha, ok.  Thank you.

Comment: are you sure you have presented the details of the problem correctly then?

Comment: Yes, the problem is reproduced as-is.

Comment: Just a nitpick: When you multiply through by $(x+1)$, you are assuming $x + 1 \gt 0$. If $x + 1 <0$, then the direction of the inequality changes.

Comment: Yes, I realised after I posted the question that I didn't add that caveat, but I did take it into consideration when I did the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\frac{(x+1)\cos(\ln(x^2))}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}$$

Take two sequences tending to $0$:

$$\begin{array}{}
a_n=\exp\left(\tfrac{\pi}{4}(1-2n)\right),&\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0\\
b_n=\exp(-n\pi),&\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n=0
\end{array}$$

We have

$$f(a_n)=\frac{(a_n+1)\cos\left(\ln\left(\exp\left(\tfrac{\pi}{4}(1-2n)\right)^2\right)\right)}{\sqrt{a_n^2+2}}
=\frac{(a_n+1)\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}(1-2n)\right)}{\sqrt{a_n^2+2}}=0$$

$$f(b_n)=\frac{(x+1)\cos(\ln(\exp(-n\pi)^2))}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}
=\frac{(x+1)\cos(-2n\pi)}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}
=\frac{b_n+1}{\sqrt{b_n^2+2}}$$

Calculating the limits of $f(a_n)$ and $f(b_n)$ we get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=0$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n)=\tfrac{\sqrt2}{2}$$

Thus the limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$$

doesn't exist.